# No Activity found to handle Intent : android.intent.action.EDIT

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to open crop intent after picking image or capturing through camera.

> Gallery :

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.EDIT");
        cropIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(file, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
```

> Camera :

```
  Intent cropIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.EDIT");
        cropIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        File file = new File(filePath);
        Log.i("checker", "does " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " exist ?" + file.exists());
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
```

It works on most of devices, but on `Galaxy Tab A (Android 11.0)` while opening edit intent it gives
**exception:**

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.EDIT dat=content://media/external/images/media/356 typ=image/* flg=0x1 (has extras) }
```

I am using This edit intent though crop intent would suffice ,because on Galaxy Tab A when recieving image through gallery, the image is rotated 90 degree counter clockwise dont know why. so using edit intent and its not working either.

Comment: Intent for crop is never a good idea on android . Because there r like 100's of manufacturers with 1000's of difference camera applications and  they don't the same scheme. Its better you should use your own Cropper.  There r lots of great implementations available open source .

Comment: @ADM can you clarify on why intent for crop is not good idea on android ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Image cropper library please review it and use it.

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop

I hope it's helpful to you!!